# Facebook login using Cordova for android and ios platform

Tags: android, ios, facebook-login, cordova-3

`Facebook login` plugin for `Cordova` mobile app `android and ios`. Using Facebook `api` I need to get the `facebook` user profile data and fetch the friends of that loggined fb user.May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Please help me. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For getting user profile data,

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown"]
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

                                  switch (state) {
                                      case FBSessionStateOpen:
                                          [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                                              if (error) {

                                                    NSLog(@"error:%@",error);


                                              }
                                              else
                                              {                                                   
                                                  // retrive user's details at here as shown below
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user first name:%@",user.first_name);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user last name:%@",user.last_name);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user birthday:%@",user.birthday);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user location:%@",user.location);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user username:%@",user.username);
                                                  NSLog(@"FB user gender:%@",[user objectForKey:@"gender"]);
                                                  NSLog(@"email id:%@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
                                                  NSLog(@"location:%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@\n\n",
                                                                         user.location[@"name"]]);

                                              }
                                          }];
                                          break;

                                      case FBSessionStateClosed:
                                      case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
                                          [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                                          break;

                                      default:
                                          break;
                                  }

                              } ];
```

For getting friends list

```
- (IBAction)friendsAction:(id)sender
    {
        if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
            // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
            [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                               allowLoginUI:YES
                                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                              FBSessionState state,
                                                              NSError *error) {
                                              if (error) {
                                                  UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" friends process cancelled"
                                                                                                      message:nil
                                                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                  [alertView show];
                                              } else if (session.isOpen) {
                                                  [self InviteAction:sender];
                                              }
                                          }];
            return;
        }

        if (self.friendPickerController == nil) {
            // Create friend picker, and get data loaded into it.
            self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
            self.friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friends";
            self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;
        }

        [self.friendPickerController loadData];
        [self.friendPickerController clearSelection];

        [self presentViewController:self.friendPickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    - (void) performPublishAction:(void (^)(void)) action
    {
        if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound)
        {
            [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                                  defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                    if (!error) {
                                                        action();
                                                    } else if (error.fberrorCategory != FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled){
                                                        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Permission denied"
                                                                                                            message:@"Unable to get permission to post"
                                                                                                           delegate:nil
                                                                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                        [alertView show];
                                                    }
                                                }];
        } else {
            action();
        }

    }



    - (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                                user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
    {
        self.loggedInUser = user;
    }


    - (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender
    {

    }

    - (void)facebookViewControllerCancelWasPressed:(id)sender {
             }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know objective c. I am developing using Cordova 3.3. I followed this link http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2014/01/facebook-login-logout-using-cordova-330.html for access FB api. The FB plugin is took out from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin. It is working fine in android. But for ios, its not clear what should i do?.